# Issue with DateCreated

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, datecreated

I have a table `dbo.participation`:

```
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,  
User VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,  
ParticipationLevel TINYINT NOT NULL,  
Selector VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,  
DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL
```

I created the code below but unfortunately it shows bad performance for `@DateStart` and `@DateStop`

```
SELECT 
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateCreated), 0) AS MDate
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 10 THEN Selector ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipationLevel1
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 30 THEN Selector ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipationLevel2
FROM 
    Participation
WHERE 
    (@DateStart IS NULL OR (@DateStart IS NOT NULL 
                            AND DateCreated >= @DateStart)) 
    AND (@DateEnd IS NULL OR (@DateEnd IS NOT NULL 
                              AND DateCreate < @DateEnd))
GROUP BY 
    Dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateCreate), 0)
```

Do you happen to have any ideas how to improve my code or alternatively how to modify the table to improve performance?

Comment: You could simplify things a little by setting DateStart to min-date if null, and DateEnd to max-date before using them in the query... eliminating two OR clauses which are always bad for performance.  Also make sure your DateCreated column has an appropriate index, with ParticipationLevel as an include column.  I don't see a definition for "Tracking" though...

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your table?. You could use an index with a key on `DateCreated` and you can include `ParticipationLevel`. Do you really need to count `Tracking`?, if that column can't have `NULL`s you could just use `COUNT(1)` instead

Comment: Both good comments above. One other piece of information? How many rows in the table? How many distinct months does it contain?

Comment: @pmbAustin I'll do as you said and no, "tracking is not there". It was my copying error that I now fixed.

Comment: @Lamak I don't have any indexes on this table yet, but I'm planning to create one on DateCreated and ParticipationLevel.

Comment: It would be better if you don't add `ParticipationLevel` as a key of the index, but as an included column.

Comment: I'll do that, but would you mind explaining why it matters? Of course only if you are free...

Comment: @MartinSmith Table has currently just over 1600 rows and it is expected to grow. 12 distinct months are there.

Comment: You'd be best off if you had "Selector" in an include column, but you can't index nvarchar(max) columns (a maximum of 400 characters will get indexed) so that will still remain a performance issue... it'll still have to do a key-lookup in order to get that information and won't be able to just stay in the index.

Comment: This is a very valid point. I didn't think about it before.

Comment: @pmb though the only information it needs is null or not null and from the table definition we know the answer so no need to reference the column at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index along the following lines

```
CREATE INDEX ix
  ON dbo.Participation(DateCreated)
  INCLUDE (ParticipationLevel);
```

And you should rewrite the query to get rid of the `OR` and to avoid the unnecessary reference to a column defined as `NOT NULL`.

(Note a simple `COUNT(Selector)` would not look up the value as SQL Server recognizes it can't be NULL but wrapping in an expression defeats this logic)

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DateCreated), 0) AS MDate,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 10 THEN 1
             END)                                         AS ParticipationLevel1,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 30 THEN 1
             END)                                         AS ParticipationLevel2
FROM   Participation
WHERE  DateCreated >= ISNULL(@DateStart, '17530101')
       AND DateCreated <= ISNULL(@DateEnd, '99991231')
GROUP  BY DATEDIFF(month, 0, DateCreated)
```

This can give a plan with a seek as below

[image]

Note that it would be possible to get rid of the sort by processing chunks of the index a month at the time (possibly in a recursive CTE) but this may be overkill.

Code for that could look something like

```
/*Cheap to find out from the index*/

IF @DateStart IS NULL
  SELECT @DateStart = MIN(DateCreated)
  FROM   dbo.Participation

IF @DateStart IS NULL
  SELECT @DateEnd = MAX(DateCreated)
  FROM   dbo.Participation

/*Adjust to start of month*/
SELECT @DateStart = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateStart), 0),
       @DateEnd = DATEADD(month, 1 + DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateEnd), 0);


WITH Dates
     AS (SELECT @DateStart AS MDate
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dateadd(MONTH, 1, MDate) AS MDate
         FROM   Dates
         WHERE  dateadd (MONTH, 1, MDate) <= @DateEnd)
SELECT D.MDate,
       CA.ParticipationLevel1,
       CA.ParticipationLevel2
FROM   Dates D
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(CASE
                                   WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 10
                                     THEN 1
                                 END) AS ParticipationLevel1,
                           COUNT(CASE
                                   WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 30
                                     THEN 1
                                 END) AS ParticipationLevel2
                    FROM   Participation P WITH (INDEX = ix)
                    WHERE  P.DateCreated >= D.MDate
                           AND P.DateCreated < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, D.MDate)
                    GROUP  BY () /* So no grouping row returned for empty months */
            ) CA(ParticipationLevel1, ParticipationLevel2)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Which gives a plan with repeated seeks and no sorts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below two checks not needed in your **WHERE** clause
@DateStart IS NOT NULL AND
@DateEnd IS NOT NULL AND

```
SELECT dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateCreated), 0) AS MDate
                ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 10 THEN Tracking ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipationLevel1
                ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ParticipationLevel >= 30 THEN Tracking ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipationLevel2
FROM Participation
WHERE (@DateStart IS NULL OR DateCreated >= @DateStart) AND (@DateEnd IS NULL OR DateCreate < @DateEnd)
GROUP BY Dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateCreate), 0)
```

Comment: That's a very superfluous condition. This shouldn't have an impact in performance (though they are unnecessary conditions)

Comment: Sorry, I saw it in the OP on second glance and withdrew my comment.